# CakePHP 3: TranslateBehavior on a model that works as an alias

Tags: php, cakephp, internationalization, associations, cakephp-3.0

In a project I have two models, Products and Packages. Packages can be seen as containers of Products and to define the items in a package I've created a model PackageItem (which is basically a Product so its using the same table). Now Products (and so PackageItems) have translatable fields such as as a title and description.

ProductsTable.php contains:

```
$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
 'fields' => ['title', 'description'],
 'translationTable' => 'products_translations'
]);
$this->belongsToMany('PackageItems', [
 'foreignKey' => 'package_id',
 'joinType' => 'LEFT',
 'joinTable'=>'products_package_items'
]);
```

PackageItemsTable contains:

```
$this->table('products');

$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
 'fields' => ['title', 'description'],
 'translationTable' => 'products_translations'
]);

$this->belongsTo('Products', [
 'foreignKey' => 'package_item_id',
 'joinType' => 'LEFT'
]);
```

Using TranslateBehavior I'm able return the translations on the Product but I can't figure out how to write the query I need to also return the translation on the PackageItems. This is my current query:

```
$package = $this->Products->find('translations')
  ->where(['business_id'=>$q['business_id'], 'id'=>$id, 'type'=>'Package'])
  ->contain([
    'PackageItems'=>[
      'Prices'=>function($q) {
        return $q->where(['product_id'=>$this->product_id]);
      }
    ]
  ])
  ->first();
```

Comment: From your code samples, your `PackageItemsTable` class doesn't seem to use the `Translate` behavior, so it's unclear what your problem is, the possibly missing behavior, or that you don't know how to set a finder for a containment?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to paste that in. I'm indeed attaching the Translate behavior to PackageItems too, its the query Im struggling with

Comment: Please put that in your question, so that people can see how exactly you are configuring it, and reproduce the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two things

### 1) Set the proper reference name

The translate behavior on the `PackageItemsTable` class needs to be configured to use the same reference name (the value that is stored in the `model` column) as the behavior on the `ProductsTable` class, otherwise you'd never receive any translations, as it would by default look for `PackageItems`.

This is what the `referenceName` option can be used for. The reference name is being derived from the class name (not the alias), or for auto-tables, from the database table name or the alias. So for your `ProductsTable` class it would be `Products`.

Either set the name manually

```
$this->addBehavior('Translate', [
    'fields' => ['title', 'description'],
    'translationTable' => 'products_translations',
    'referenceName' => 'Products' // there it goes
]);
```

or retrieve it dynamically from the behavior on the `ProductsTable`, like

```
$referenceName = $this->Products
    ->target()
    ->behaviors()
    ->get('Translate')
    ->config('referenceName');
```

This however would need to be done *after* adding the corresponding `belongsTo` association for the `Products` table!

### 2) Use the `translations` finder for the containment

You need to configure the `PackageItems` containment to use the `translations` finder, which is as simple as

```
contain([
    'PackageItems' => [
        'finder' => 'translations', // there you go
        'Prices' => function ($q) {
            return $q->where(['product_id' => $this->product_id]);
        }
    ]
])
```

### See also

- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TranslateBehavior::_referenceName()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.TranslateBehavior.html#__referenceName)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Behavior\TranslateBehavior::$_defaultConfig](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Behavior.TranslateBehavior.html#$_defaultConfig)**
- **[API > \Cake\ORM\Query::contain()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.ORM.Query.html#_contain)**